# Как "k","кк","ккк" переделать в нули

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Как мне сделать чтобы нельзя было писать по типу:
-казино 100кк
Или как эти 100кк переделать в число, чтобы в последней строке кода не выходила ошибка.
Вместо 100кк может быть любое число c "kk".

```
elif (bodyone[0] in ("казино","Казино")) and (len(bodyone)>1):
    if bodyone[1] in ("все","всё","Всё","Все"):
        (тут код, это не важно)
    elif int(bodyone[1]) <= int(data[str(id)]["money"]):
        (тут код, это не важно)
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией **replace**

`bodyone[1] = bodyone[1].replace('k', '000')`

Тогда строка **100кк** превратится в **100000000**

Answer (score 0):

Просто замените символы `k` на нули методом `replace`

```
elif (bodyone[0] in ("казино","Казино")) and (len(bodyone)>1):
    if bodyone[1] in ("все","всё","Всё","Все"):
        (тут код, это не важно)
    elif int(bodyone[1].replace('k', '0')) <= int(data[str(id)]["money"]):
        (тут код, это не важно)
```